# Spark Standalone Mode: Workers not stopping properly

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

When stopping a whole cluster in spark (0.7.0) with

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/stop-all.sh
```

not all workers are stopped correctly.
More specifically, if I then want to restart the cluster with

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/start-all.sh
```

I get:

```
host1: starting spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to [...]
host3: starting spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to [...]
host2: starting spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to [...]
host5: starting spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to [...]
host4: spark.deploy.worker.Worker running as process 8104. Stop it first.
host7: spark.deploy.worker.Worker running as process 32452. Stop it first.
host6: starting spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to [...]
```

On host4 and host7, there is indeed a StandaloneExecutorBackend still running:

```sh
$ jps
27703 Worker
27763 StandaloneExecutorBackend
28601 Jps
```

Simply repeating

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/stop-all.sh
```

unfortunately also doesn't stop the workers. Spark just tells me that the workers are about to be stopped:

```
host2: no spark.deploy.worker.Worker to stop
host7: stopping spark.deploy.worker.Worker
host1: no spark.deploy.worker.Worker to stop
host4: stopping spark.deploy.worker.Worker
host6: no spark.deploy.worker.Worker to stop
host5: no spark.deploy.worker.Worker to stop
host3: no spark.deploy.worker.Worker to stop
```

no `spark.deploy.master.Master` to stop

However,

```sh
$ jps
27703 Worker
27763 StandaloneExecutorBackend
28601 Jps
```

says otherwise.
Does someone have an idea how `stop-all.sh` would work properly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason seemed to have been that the attempt to cache the whole dataset was causing the Worker machines to swap in a large manner. In this case, the number of worker machines was just too small for the dataset.